# Getting stream closed exception in YouTube Analytics java servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, youtube-api

I am using you tube analytics api in java. I have a jsp page which calls a servlet in which this code is written -

```
final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

      /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
       final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

      /** Global instance of Youtube object to make general YouTube API requests. */
      YouTube youtube;

      /** Global instance of YoutubeAnalytics object to make analytic API requests. */
      YouTubeAnalytics analytics;


      Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(YouTubeAnalyticsReports.class.getResourceAsStream("client_secrets.json"));

      String access_token = null;
      String id           = null;
    // Scopes required to access YouTube general and analytics information.
      List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
        );


    try {

            Credential credential = YouTubeAnalyticsReports.authorize(scopes);



      }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After executing this code a new tab open in browser to autorize the user then it saves the credentials. but the tab in which the jsp page has called the servlet always show loading after this . Because of that if i again try to execute this code then it gives stream closed exception. Now what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution of this....i didn't use Desktop.Browse for the url. Now i am simply getting the url and opening the url in same tab.